# Module object has no attribute 'float_power'

Tags: python, numpy

Trying this simple example to check float_power() function but I get the error

**AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'float_power'**

Any ideas why?

```
import numpy as np 

# input_array 
arr1 = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2] 
arr2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
print ("arr1         : ", arr1) 
print ("arr1         : ", arr2) 

# output_array 
out = np.float_power(arr1, arr2)
```

Comment: I tried it in my machine it gave no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has no errors, check [here](https://repl.it/repls/SoulfulWeeElectricity).

Try to reinstall `numpy` with `--upgrade` flag.

```
pip3 install --upgrade numpy
```

According to [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.float_power.html) you need at least version **1.12.0**.